Cannot shrink log file
I cannot shrink a log file, for a database that is in Simple recovery model (used to be in Full , and was changed to Simple).
I have tried every solution I can find on the internet, even the mighty chatGPT is clueless. So am I. I have tried switching back to Full recovery, backing up DB, the Log, nothing.
Sharing what I have tried:
I am totally out of ideas what could be happening...






5 GB data and 300 MB log is tiny.  There are only downsides to shrinking a log file unless the 300 MB of space used is causing problems.  This seems like a pointless endeavor unless you can justify otherwise.

hmm... this particular database, the size is inconsequential, I was just using it as an example, as I have larger DBs where I have a similar issue. I thought I could get it down to something much smaller. I guess the answer is that it is impossible?

@GregBala "I guess the answer is that it is impossible?" - TBH, the answer is it's bad practice, regardless if it's possible. You shouldn't be routinely shrinking your Log files.

I am routinely doing so, I just have large DBs with almost 0 write activity, with very large transaction log files. I'd like to move them, but the size of transaction logs are giving me trouble ( not this example).

You are down to two Virtual Log Files (VLFs). You can't have fewer than that. The file is as small as it can be. And, as mentioned, 300 MB for 5 GB data is pretty small already.
Log files are shrunk by SQL Server removing un-used VLFs from the end towards the beginning of the file. The last-most used VLF sets the limit for how small the ldf can be. And, again, two VLFs is the minimum number of VLFs.
If you have more then two VLFs, you need to make sure that you have unused VLFs at the end. You do this by repeatedly empty the log (CHECKPOINT or BACKUP LOG) and SHRINK. Repeat as many as it takes. Typically, you have to do this between 2 and 5 times.
There are some details in by below article, but in the end, you just have to repeat shrink and empty. And of course, make sure that nothing is holding up the log file (open transactions, replication, availability group, etc).
https://karaszi.com/large-transaction-log-file

Hi Tibor. If you observe the output of the VLFs you will note that they are from two different physical transaction log files (column FileId) . OP has two TLOG files which isn't the best recommendation anyway.  He could move the data from the smaller TLOG file to the larger TLOG file and possibly achieve better results. Then again a TLOG file created from the default model database is generally around 64 MB, so there is some space for improvement somewhere.

@JohnK.N. Agreed. I didn't notice that there are two ldf's. Each have only two VLFs so none of them can be shrunk (to clarify to the OP). I agree, getting rid of one of them would be the way to go. And, indeed have a look at model, why the two initial VLFs are so "big".

I was having issues some time ago with VLFs and looking for a way to look at the VLF information of a given database. So I asked a question and  Paul's solution provided me with a way to see the VLF information grouped together.
Depending on the output, you might see a reason why the Transaction Log file can't be shrunk. (split VLF file groups)
There is a script from the Tiger Toolbox that might assist you with your resizing issues. It can be found at microsoft/tigertoolbox(Public) - Fix_VLFs.sql (Github | TigerToolbox)
Seeing as the internet is a volatile place I will reproduce Tiger Toolbox script here for your convenience:
-- 2011-05-24 Pedro Lopes (Microsoft) pedro.lopes@microsoft.com (http://aka.ms/sqlinsights)
--
-- 2012-03-25 Added SQL 2012 support
-- 2012-09-19 Simplified logic
-- 2012-09-20 Changed grow settings if not SQL Server 2012
--
-- Generates the sql statements to preemtively fix VLF issues in all DBs within the server, based on the transaction log current size.
--
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000), @dbname VARCHAR(255), @count int, @usedlogsize bigint, @logsize bigint
DECLARE @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(1000), @sqlparam NVARCHAR(100), @filename VARCHAR(255), @i int, @recmodel NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @potsize int, @n_iter int, @n_iter_final int, @initgrow int, @n_init_iter int, @bckpath NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @majorver smallint, @minorver smallint, @build smallint

CREATE TABLE #loginfo (dbname varchar(100), num_of_rows int, used_logsize_MB DECIMAL(20,1))

DECLARE @tblvlf TABLE (dbname varchar(100), 
    Actual_log_size_MB DECIMAL(20,1), 
    Potential_log_size_MB DECIMAL(20,1), 
    Actual_VLFs int, 
    Potential_VLFs int, 
    Growth_iterations int,
    Log_Initial_size_MB DECIMAL(20,1), 
    File_autogrow_MB DECIMAL(20,1))
    
SELECT TOP 1 @bckpath = REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(physical_device_name), LEN(physical_device_name)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(physical_device_name),0))) FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily WHERE device_type = 2

SELECT @majorver = (@@microsoftversion / 0x1000000) & 0xff, @minorver = (@@microsoftversion / 0x10000) & 0xff, @build = @@microsoftversion & 0xffff
 
--DECLARE csr CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE dbid > 4 AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name,'status') = 'ONLINE' AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name,'Updateability') = 'READ_WRITE' AND name <> 'tempdb' AND name <> 'ReportServerTempDB'
DECLARE csr CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE is_read_only = 0 AND state = 0 AND database_id <> 2;
OPEN csr
FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @dbname
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #log_info (recoveryunitid int NULL,
    fileid tinyint,
    file_size bigint,
    start_offset bigint,
    FSeqNo int,
    [status] tinyint,
    parity tinyint,
    create_lsn numeric(25,0))

    SET @query = 'DBCC LOGINFO (' + '''' + @dbname + ''') WITH NO_INFOMSGS'
    IF @majorver < 11
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #log_info (fileid, file_size, start_offset, FSeqNo, [status], parity, create_lsn)
        EXEC (@query)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #log_info (recoveryunitid, fileid, file_size, start_offset, FSeqNo, [status], parity, create_lsn)
        EXEC (@query)
    END
    SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @usedlogsize = (SELECT (MIN(l.start_offset) + SUM(CASE WHEN l.status <> 0 THEN l.file_size ELSE 0 END))/1024.00/1024.00 FROM #log_info l)
    DROP TABLE #log_info;
    INSERT #loginfo
    VALUES(@dbname, @count, @usedlogsize);
    FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE csr
DEALLOCATE csr

PRINT '/* Generated on ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, GETDATE()) + ' in ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */' + CHAR(10)
    
DECLARE cshrk CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT dbname, num_of_rows FROM #loginfo 
WHERE num_of_rows >= 50 --My rule of thumb is 50 VLFs. Your mileage may vary.
ORDER BY dbname
OPEN cshrk
FETCH NEXT FROM cshrk INTO @dbname, @count
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlcmd = 'SELECT @nameout = name, @logsizeout = (CAST(size AS BIGINT)*8)/1024 FROM [' + @dbname + '].dbo.sysfiles WHERE (64 & status) = 64'
    SET @sqlparam = '@nameout NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT, @logsizeout bigint OUTPUT'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlcmd, @sqlparam, @nameout = @filename OUTPUT, @logsizeout = @logsize OUTPUT;
    PRINT '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '
    PRINT CHAR(13) + 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ';'
    PRINT 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + @filename + ''', 1, TRUNCATEONLY);'
    PRINT '--'
    PRINT '-- CHECK: if the tlog file has shrunk with the following query:'
    PRINT 'SELECT name, (size*8)/1024 AS log_MB FROM [' + @dbname + '].dbo.sysfiles WHERE (64 & status) = 64'
    PRINT '--'
    SET @recmodel = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@dbname,'Recovery'))
    IF @recmodel <> 'SIMPLE' 
    AND SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 8 -- This cannot be applied on Managed Instance
    BEGIN
        PRINT '-- If the log has not shrunk, you must backup the transaction log next.'
        PRINT '-- Repeat the backup and shrink process alternatively until you get the desired log size (about 1MB).'
        PRINT '--'
        PRINT '-- METHOD: Backup -> Shrink (repeat the backup and shrink process until the log has shrunk):'
        PRINT '--'
        PRINT '-- Create example logical backup device.' 
        PRINT 'USE master;' + CHAR(13) + 'EXEC sp_addumpdevice ''disk'', ''BckLog'', ''' + @bckpath + '\example_bck.trn'';'
        PRINT 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ';'
        PRINT '-- Backup Log'
        PRINT 'BACKUP LOG ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ' TO BckLog;'
        PRINT '-- Shrink'
        PRINT 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + @filename + ''', 1);'
        PRINT '--'
        PRINT '-- METHOD: Alter recovery model -> Shrink:'
        PRINT '-- NOTE: Because the database is in ' + @recmodel + ' recovery model, one alternative is to set it to SIMPLE to truncate the log, shrink it, and reset it to ' + @recmodel + '.'
        PRINT '-- NOTE2: This method of setting the recovery model to SIMPLE and back again WILL BREAK log chaining, and thus any log shipping or mirroring.'
        PRINT 'USE [master]; ' + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;'
        PRINT 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ';' + CHAR(13) + 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + @filename + ''', 1);'
        PRINT 'USE [master]; ' + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ' SET RECOVERY ' + @recmodel + ';'
        PRINT '--'
        PRINT '-- CHECK: if the tlog file has shrunk with the following query:'
        PRINT 'SELECT name, (size*8)/1024 AS log_MB FROM [' + @dbname + '].dbo.sysfiles WHERE (64 & status) = 64'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT '-- If not, then proceed to the next step (it may be necessary to execute multiple times):'
        PRINT 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + @filename + ''', 1);'
        PRINT '-- CHECK: if the tlog file has shrunk with the following query:'
        PRINT 'SELECT name, (size*8)/1024 AS log_MB FROM [' + @dbname + '].dbo.sysfiles WHERE (64 & status) = 64'
    END

    -- We are growing in MB instead of GB because of known issue prior to SQL 2012.
    -- More detail here: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Bug-log-file-growth-broken-for-multiples-of-4GB.aspx
    -- and http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/481594/log-growth-not-working-properly-with-specific-growth-sizes-vlfs-also-not-created-appropriately
    -- or https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/357502/transaction-log-file-size-will-not-grow-exactly-4gb-when-filegrowth-4gb
    IF @majorver >= 11
    BEGIN
        SET @n_iter = (SELECT CASE WHEN @logsize <= 64 THEN 1
            WHEN @logsize > 64 AND @logsize < 256 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/256, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 256 AND @logsize < 1024 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/512, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 1024 AND @logsize < 4096 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/1024, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 4096 AND @logsize < 8192 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/2048, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 8192 AND @logsize < 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/4096, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/8192, 0)
            END)
        SET @potsize = (SELECT CASE WHEN @logsize <= 64 THEN 1*64
            WHEN @logsize > 64 AND @logsize < 256 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/256, 0)*256
            WHEN @logsize >= 256 AND @logsize < 1024 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/512, 0)*512
            WHEN @logsize >= 1024 AND @logsize < 4096 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/1024, 0)*1024
            WHEN @logsize >= 4096 AND @logsize < 8192 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/2048, 0)*2048
            WHEN @logsize >= 8192 AND @logsize < 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/4096, 0)*4096
            WHEN @logsize >= 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/8192, 0)*8192
            END)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @n_iter = (SELECT CASE WHEN @logsize <= 64 THEN 1
            WHEN @logsize > 64 AND @logsize < 256 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/256, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 256 AND @logsize < 1024 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/512, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 1024 AND @logsize < 4096 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/1024, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 4096 AND @logsize < 8192 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/2048, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 8192 AND @logsize < 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/4000, 0)
            WHEN @logsize >= 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/8000, 0)
            END)
        SET @potsize = (SELECT CASE WHEN @logsize <= 64 THEN 1*64
            WHEN @logsize > 64 AND @logsize < 256 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/256, 0)*256
            WHEN @logsize >= 256 AND @logsize < 1024 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/512, 0)*512
            WHEN @logsize >= 1024 AND @logsize < 4096 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/1024, 0)*1024
            WHEN @logsize >= 4096 AND @logsize < 8192 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/2048, 0)*2048
            WHEN @logsize >= 8192 AND @logsize < 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/4000, 0)*4000
            WHEN @logsize >= 16384 THEN ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, ROUND(@logsize, -2))/8000, 0)*8000
            END)
    END
    
    -- If the proposed log size is smaller than current log, and also smaller than 4GB,
    -- and there is less than 512MB of diff between the current size and proposed size, add 1 grow.
    SET @n_iter_final = @n_iter
    IF @logsize > @potsize AND @potsize <= 4096 AND ABS(@logsize - @potsize) < 512
    BEGIN
        SET @n_iter_final = @n_iter + 1
    END
    -- If the proposed log size is larger than current log, and also larger than 50GB, 
    -- and there is less than 1GB of diff between the current size and proposed size, take 1 grow.
    ELSE IF @logsize < @potsize AND @potsize <= 51200 AND ABS(@logsize - @potsize) > 1024
    BEGIN
        SET @n_iter_final = @n_iter - 1
    END

    IF @potsize = 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @potsize = 64 
    END
    IF @n_iter = 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @n_iter = 1
    END
    
    SET @potsize = (SELECT CASE WHEN @n_iter < @n_iter_final THEN @potsize + (@potsize/@n_iter) 
            WHEN @n_iter > @n_iter_final THEN @potsize - (@potsize/@n_iter) 
            ELSE @potsize END)
    
    SET @n_init_iter = @n_iter_final
    IF @potsize >= 8192
    BEGIN
        SET @initgrow = @potsize/@n_iter_final
    END
    IF @potsize >= 64 AND @potsize <= 512
    BEGIN
        SET @n_init_iter = 1
        SET @initgrow = 512
    END
    IF @potsize > 512 AND @potsize <= 1024
    BEGIN
        SET @n_init_iter = 1
        SET @initgrow = 1023
    END
    IF @potsize > 1024 AND @potsize < 8192
    BEGIN
        SET @n_init_iter = 1
        SET @initgrow = @potsize
    END

    INSERT INTO @tblvlf
    SELECT @dbname, @logsize, @potsize, @count, 
        CASE WHEN @potsize <= 64 THEN (@potsize/(@potsize/@n_init_iter))*4
            WHEN @potsize > 64 AND @potsize < 1024 THEN (@potsize/(@potsize/@n_init_iter))*8
            WHEN @potsize >= 1024 THEN (@potsize/(@potsize/@n_init_iter))*16
            END, 
        @n_init_iter, @initgrow, CASE WHEN (@potsize/@n_iter_final) <= 1024 THEN (@potsize/@n_iter_final) ELSE 1024 END
    
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE @i <= @n_init_iter
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 1
        BEGIN
            --Log Autogrow should not be above 1GB
            PRINT CHAR(13) + '-- Now for the log file growth:'
            PRINT 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N''' + @filename + ''', SIZE = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @initgrow) + 'MB , FILEGROWTH = ' + CASE WHEN (@potsize/@n_iter_final) <= 1024 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, (@potsize/@n_iter_final)) ELSE '1024' END + 'MB );'
        END
        IF @i > 1
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N''' + @filename + ''', SIZE = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @initgrow*@i)+ 'MB );'
        END     
        SET @i = @i + 1
        CONTINUE
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cshrk INTO @dbname, @count
END
CLOSE cshrk
DEALLOCATE cshrk;

DROP TABLE #loginfo;

SELECT dbname AS [Database_Name], Actual_log_size_MB, Potential_log_size_MB, Actual_VLFs, 
    Potential_VLFs, Growth_iterations, Log_Initial_size_MB, File_autogrow_MB
FROM @tblvlf;
GO

Other Things to Do
If possible I would try and merge the information from the second transaction log file into the first tlog file and remove the additional tlog file, according to the statement here:
(emphasis mine)

Add or enlarge a log file
You can gain space by enlarging the existing log file (if disk space permits) or adding a log file to the database, typically on a different disk. One transaction log file is sufficient unless log space is running out and disk space is also running out on the volume that holds the log file.

Reference Manage the size of the transaction log file (Microsoft Learn | SQL)
You can merge the second tlog file into the first via the GUI of the Shrink File dialog which you are already aware of.
Other recommendations can be found in the article Troubleshoot a full transaction log (SQL Server Error 9002) (Microsoft Learn | SQL)

Thank you, I will look into this. I have the 2nd log file, as I was experimenting with a solution to add that second log file, which was supposed to empty the first one. It kind of worked, as adding the 2nd log file, immediately release the 1st file's half of space (went down from 600MB to 300MB)
